# Inverse element in associative structure not necessarily unique

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, monoid

I read from the link[here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_in_Associative_Structure_is_Unique) proving that the inverse element in associative structure should be unique. However, it's only proving that should there exist a left and a right inverse element, then they should be identical. And I remember reading examples in non-commutative rings (so there should also be a similar case in monoids), an element has multiple multiplicative left inverse elements. But I'm not quite sure anymore. Could anybody reproduce such an example?

Also, interestingly, even for non-commutative groups, the inverse element is unique. Does all of this have to do with the fact that every element in the group is assigned with an inverse element?

Comment: Let $E$ be a set and let $S$ be the semigroup of all maps $f:E\to E.$ If $f$ is injective but not surjective, then $f$ has more than one left inverse but no right inverse. If $f$ is surjective but not injective, then $f$ has more than one right inverse but no left inverse.

Comment: *However, it's only proving that should there exist a left and a right inverse element, then they should be identical.* Well, yes, if you have that then it's obvious there's only one left inverse. If $a'$ is any left inverse of $a$, then $a'a=1$, and right multiplying with $a^{-1}$ you get $a'=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. One can construct such an example using a qoutient of a polynomial ring (of noncommutative variables). 
   Or, take the monoid $E$ of functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ under composition. Now, e.g. $s:n\mapsto n+1$ has infinitely many left inverses, as it has freedom on what to assign to $0\notin{\rm im}(s)$. 
   If you want, you can make a ring out of this by adding elements (with integer [or whatever] coefficients) freely - denoted by $\Bbb Z[E]\ $ [or $R[E]$ for arbitrary coefficient ring $R$]. 
   For another example, along the same line, we can find a linear operator corresponding to $s$ on an infinite dimensional vector space (e.g. separable Hilbert space).
2. There are more axiom systems for defining a group. Some of them requires the unary *inverse operation* as part of the algebraic structure, others prove the existence and unqiueness of the identity and the inverses.
   In the end, all these axiom systems turn out to describe the same.